# the number of ways to order a line from a group of 6 women and 2 men such that 2 men stand on either end?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Given a group of 6 women and 2 men, I have to find the number of ways in which atleast one man is on one end of the line.

I tried to separate the cases where both men take the ends and when only one man takes an end.

When both men take ends:

$$2! \times 6!$$

When only one man takes an end:

$$ \binom{2}{1} \times \binom{6}{1} \times 5! \times 2 $$

However, I am getting an incorrect answer(It is 18720), could someone help me?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to save your reasoning but I would do it that way :
Count the number of ways that a man takes the left end (regardless of whether or not the right end is taken by the other man)
Then the number of ways that a man takes the right end (it's the same number). 
Finally subtract the number of ways the men take both ends because you have counted it twice in the previous calculations (you already have that number)
Good luck !

Comment: Yeah as you can maybe see from @Anthony's  answer, the problem is that you have ignored the second man in your scenario with only one man at the end. His position will change the permutations of the women.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the permutations of the two men i.e, 8 choose 2, but then remove the double counting:
$$
(8 \text{ choose } 2) * 6! - 2!*6! = 18720
$$

Comment: To obtain $\binom{n}{k}$, type `$\binom{n}{k}$`.

Answer (score 5):

When only one man is at one end, it should be

$ \displaystyle \binom{2}{1} \binom{6}{1} \cdot 2! \cdot 6! = 17280$

That is we choose one of the men and one of the women to be at two ends and as they can swap their places, we multiply by $2!$. Then remaining six people can be arranged in $6!$ ways.

When both men are at two ends, it is $~2! \cdot 6! = 1440~$, as you mentioned.

Adding them, you get the right answer.

Using complementary method -

When no man is at either end, we have $5$ places for the first man and $6$ for the second. Women can be arranged in $6!$ ways. Subtracting it from total number of ways to arrange all $8$ of them, we should get the desired number of arrangements. That is,

$8! - 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 6! = 18720$